# Обращение к WSDL из PHP

Tags: wsdl, php

Возникла необходимость обращения к WSLD из PHP. 
C сервисом WSDL работал только один раз и только с python - особых проблем не возникло, но с PHP никак не могу разобраться.
В общем, создаю клиент:

```
$url = "https://myairops.com/OpisService/AiropsScheduleDataService.svc?singleWsdl";
$airopsClient = new SoapClient($airopsUrl);
var_dump($airopsClient->__getFunctions()); // ExportScheduleData(ExportScheduleData $parameters)
$airopsClient->ExportScheduleData(array());
```

Получаю:

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

Хорошо, поискал в сети, нашел, что нужно использовать SOAP 1.2

пересоздаю объект:

```
$airopsClient = new SoapClient($url,
    array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$airopsClient->ExportScheduleData(array());
```

И все. При попытке загрузить страницу с кодом она не загружается и висит бесконечно в состоянии запроса.

кто-нибудь подскажет как решить проблему?

============== 01.12.2014 ===========

Похоже, сервис использует WS-Security. Дали сертификат. пытаюсь авторизоваться пр помощи сертификата:

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to set local cert chain file `C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\sandbox.dev\public\sandbox.cer'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\sandbox.dev\public\sandbox.php on line 34
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Клиент с использованием wsse](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381087/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-wsse)

Answer (score 1):

Решение в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/381087/php-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-wsse) вопросе. Была проблема с проверкой подлинности.