# Клиент с использованием wsse

Tags: wsdl, php, soap, безопасность

Вопрос частично поднимал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/378976/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-wsdl-%D0%B8%D0%B7-php).
Есть WSDL сервис, который использует WSSE. От техподдержки мне удалось выяснить, что авторизация происходит по паре логин, пароль. Но для проверки подлинности HTTPS соединения используется публичный сертификат и публичный ключ.

Не очень силен в SOAP  и тем более в Soap+wsse, но в xml документе есть тег:

```
<sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
```

Насколько я понял, это говорит, что не нужно wsse заголовки подписывать сертификатом.
Гугление первых нескольких страниц и разбор примеров - не один из предложенных вариантов не подходит. Нашел примеры, где используется логин + пароль в wsse, но не авторизуется. Попытка добавить сертификат в 'local_cert' выдает только ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, так и не удалось реализовать это все на чистом php. Сделал в связке с java.
Более подробный ответ читайте на [форуме](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-ws-security-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-soap-%D0%B2-php-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82.49762/page-2#post-718387)